# How to submit for after all the fields are filled in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have a HTML form that contains a textbox and a submit button, what I want is when I pressed submit button it should check for the textbox that it have no error then proceed with submission.

Here is my button code:

```
 <form id="thisform">
 <div id="Registeration" class="Registeration">
            <input type="text" id="textbox" class="textbox"
            placeholder="My textbox" name="fBox" maxlength="30"/>
        </div>

<div class="Registration_Submit_Div">
    <input type="submit" value="submitform" id="SumbitForm_btn" class="SumbitForm_btn" name="Submit_btn" onclick="submit()"/>
</div></form>

function(){
    alert('hello');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Show your complete code, your code has no textbox. You call a submit function that doesnt exist

Comment: i edited my question and posted the full form

Comment: Where is your submit function or submit handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plain JS example where the form is only submitted if the text is at least 5 characters long.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <form method="POST" action="result.html" class="da-form">
    <input type="text" name="textbox" class="textbox">
    <input type="submit" class="submit">
  </form>

  <script>

    var formEl = document.querySelector('.da-form');
    var submitBtn = document.querySelector('.da-form .submit');
    var textEl = document.querySelector('.textbox');

    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (textEl.value.length >= 5) {
        formEl.submit();
      } else {
        console.error('text should be at least 5 chars long');
      }
      console.log();
    });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use AngularJS:

Angular allow you to get status about your form: $invalid/$valid

the following code will disable the button until the form will be valid:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()" class="button" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
```

please see the following example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
<form ng-controller="FormController" name="myForm">
   <div class="header padding-b--10">Form Area</div>
        <div class="padding-b--10">
            <input name="empId" placeholder="Employee ID" ng-model="data.empId"
                   style="padding:5px" required/> 
            <span ng-if="myForm.empId.$dirty && myForm.empId.$invalid" ng-bind="invalid" class="error"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="padding-b--10">
            <input name="empEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="data.empEmail"
                   style="padding:5px" required/>
            <span ng-if="myForm.empEmail.$dirty && myForm.empEmail.$invalid" ng-bind="invalid" class="error"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="submit()" class="button" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">

</form>
```

Controller:

```
    function FormController($scope){

    $scope.invalid = "Invalid";

    $scope.submit = function(){
        console.log($scope.data);
    }

};
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/pqz3hsac/22/